# Can i get app information when i installing iOS app in iPhone device

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can i get app information in installation time. using objective c.
Step :-

1. I click app icon in app store.
2. When downloading start ( on progress) in iPhone/iPad.
3. That time i required app information.

Its possible or not. if its possible please provide me right suggestion.

Comment: No, you can only know when someone runs the app.

Comment: I guess, until the installation starts you cannot get app info, unless you get the same from app store(I guess you are not looking for that way)!

Comment: No, you can not. can you describe in little detail, what you want do here. may be we have some solution for that case.

Comment: Actually i required app information for showing list with details and number of count of installation in our app.